# Memory allocation while using automatic reference counting

Tags: iphone, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I am using automatic reference counting in my project .I have three screens . on first screen there is button to go on the second screen having table view with the links.when I clicked on the link it opens inside the web view on another view controller . I am using navigation controller to navigate between the screens .
 Now while profiling the application I was monitoring the memory allocations .I found that the live bytes on first screen is 5.27 and when I clicked on the button to go on next screen the reading was 5.45 when i go back to the first screen again the reading was 5.36 there was small difference between initial(5.27) and final(5.36) value on the first screen .Fine . But when i go to the second screen again and from second screen when I open the link inside the web view the reading was 7.93.when i navigated to the first screen again the reading was 6.57. So there is big difference between initial and final readings on the first screen when I opened the web view. What is the reason that I am getting the difference between the readings? where did that ext a byte used for when I  am getting memory leaks 0.

Comment: this happens with ARC, it stores in autorelease pool, But doesnot release it as soon as it is out of scope or lifetime. It remains there, unless OS needs that memory.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya That's just wrong. ARC does not perform any caching or otherwise keep memory around until needed by the OS.

Comment: @Nikolai I think what he meant was that objects in an autorelease pool don't just deallocate themselves like normal, instead they are released en masse when their pool drains.

Comment: so objects are in autorelease pool but they aren't destroyed yet thats why the problem ? But I am getting considerable difference while loading of the web view

Answer (score 1):

its due to the caching, call this to free all the fat when u receive a memory warning

```
 [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
```

and you can configure the cache by following call, when the APp starts

```
 int cacheSizeMemory = 4*1024*1024; 
int cacheSizeDisk = 32*1024*1024; 
NSURLCache *sharedCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:cacheSizeMemory diskCapacity:cacheSizeDisk diskPath:@"nsurlcache"];
[NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:sharedCache];
```

Comment: I never received memory warning.

Comment: you can just forget about it , if set your cache policy and clear it on memory warning.Make sure that you are not retaining your UIWebViews via retain cycles.